# Change color for a Swipe Card not working (lorentzos Swipecards)

Tags: java, android, swipecardview

I am building an app that uses:

```
implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9@aar'
```

for  Swipe Cards. [level 1 color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ05Z.png), [level 2 color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d48Pq.png)

It changes the color of the card but not on the com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView itself.

If I set the color for com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView it only changes the background color, not the color of the card.

The implementation has its own Adapter here:

```
//questions from the MainActivity.class
ArrayList <String>  questionsList = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("levelList");

SwipeFlingAdapterView swipeFlingAdapterView = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.card);

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.details, R.id.card_text, questionsList );

swipeFlingAdapterView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I want to change the color of the swipe card depending on the level provided (there are currently 3 levels). Using the :

```
//gets the color for each level
String cardColor = intent.getStringExtra("cardColorBackground");
//Sets the color for the card
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cardColor));
```

does not work. It changes the color of the card, but not on the

```
com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
```

itself.

I guess I have to make my own Adapter, but I don't know what to change for it.

Can you please help ?
Much appreciated!
P.S: I am still learning Java Android, I am currently a college student and want to work in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by making my own Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter.
Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mData;
    private int mResource;
    private int mTextViewResourceId;
    private int mColor;

    public MyCustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects, int color) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mTextViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        mData = objects;
        mColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mColor);
        return view;
    }
}
```